# У меня из-за баджа нарушается работоспособность всего кода, показывает false, в переменную записывается как true

Tags: c#

Не первый раз с этим приколом сталкиваюсь, не думаю, что я где-то косячу.

Вот кусок кода, он отвечает за проверку потока, выполнил ли он свою задачу, или нет.

```
for (int task = 0; task < taskarray.Length; task++)
{
    bool whta = false;
    bool aboba = false;
    bool aboba1 = false;
    bool amogus = false;

    try
    {
        aboba = !freetasks.Contains(task);
        aboba1 = freetasks[task] == -1;
        amogus = taskarray[task].Status.Equals(TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
        whta = taskarray[task].Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && (!freetasks.Contains(task) && freetasks[task] == -1);
    }catch(Exception exc)
    { Console.WriteLine(exc); }
        
    if (whta == true)
    {
        var status = taskarray[task].Status;
        bool what = !freetasks.Contains(task);
        AddAndSortArray(task);
    }
}

...

private void AddAndSortArray(int task)
{
    for(var taskplace = 0; taskplace<freetasks.Length; taskplace++)
    {
        if (freetasks[taskplace] == -1)
        {
            freetasks[taskplace] = task;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Переменные я специально объявил, чтобы при отладке посмотреть, почему когда у меня должен быть `false` в `if`, возвращается `true`

Вот скриншоты, что происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепляю рабочий код +-, вместо while(true) Должно быть событие OnMessage, но тут я это не сделаю
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DXCk35

Если запустить, видно, что создается кучу тасков, до завершения 2ух.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема, и как это видно? Из вашего скриншота ничего не понятно, если честно.

Comment: Пролема в том, что условие = `false`, а в переменной каким-то чудом `=true`

Comment: Статус моего Таска `Task = Running`, я его сравниваю со статусом `RunToCompletion`.        Если самому подумать, ясно что должно выдать `false` они же разные, программа тоже так думает, и в отладчике показывает, что эти условия не равны, выдает `false`. Но в переменной каким-то чудом, появляется `true`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я понимаю, но увы, без скриншота тут никак. Ибо легче показать, чем описывать, или кому-то проверять

Comment: Ну, со скриншотом у нас нет никакого шанса воспроизвести вашу проблему, поэтому и вероятность ответа не слишком высокая. Если реально хотите ответ, сделайте [mcve].

Comment: Хорошо, я сейчас код скину

Comment: Нет, весь код не нужно, только минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Вот например, переменная `aboba` — она нужна для понимания проблемы? Если нет, уберите её из вашего примера. Цикл по `taskarray` тоже необходим, без него проблема не воспроизводится? Если не необходим, уберите его тоже, Оставьте самый минимум.

Comment: Да все переменные нужны, чтобы вы смогли увидеть, что должно вернуться `false`, а в переменной `true`

Comment: 1) Называйте переменные нормально. Нет никакого желания разбираться, что означают переменные навроде `wtf` или `abibas`. А вот `isTaskRunning` - хорошее название. 2) Когда вы пишете `в переменной каким-то чудом =true` - пишите тут и название переменной, о которой вы говорите, телепатов тут на форуме немного.

Comment: У вас в коде, тем не менее, нигда не читается значение переменной `aboba`. Вы уверены, что она нужна в контексте вопроса?

Comment: @VladD Да, я сейчас их уберу. Нужная получается firstchek

Comment: @CrazyElf ```amogus```,  если смотреть на ```.netfiddle```, там называется `firstchek`

Comment: Осталось понять, что такое "баджа"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас скорее всего race condition.

У вас в одном потоке идёт цикл `RecerveFreeTasks` (запущен через `Task.Run`), а в другом (`Main`) вы меняете `freetasks` и `taskarray`. Так делать нельзя хотя бы потому, что в момент сразу после чтения `freetasks[i]` внутри цикла значение может измениться.

Используйте mutex вокруг блоков изменений.